# How does one pronounce 'Servilia'?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

I am giving a presentation on women in Rome, and one of my chosen women is named Servilia, the mother of Brutus.

I was curious how to pronounce her name, as I know Romans used the letter 'v' to signify a 'u' type sound (as in Julius) as well as to signify a 'v' type sound (as in victory).

Any ideas on this?

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Do you want to know how she would have pronounced it, or how English-speakers pronounce it nowadays? The two are quite different.

Answer (score 4):

The name *Servilia* would be pronounced **Sair-wee-lee-ah**, with the stress on the third to last syllable, in Classical Latin. However, in Anglicized versions of Latin names, you see a few changes. In this case, the above would become **Sihr-vih-lee-yah**. Please see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_spelling_and_pronunciation) on more general pronunciation of Latin, and [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin) on the pronunciation of Latin words in English.

---

The reason I used the method I did for pronunciation is that the traditional IPA method can be confusing to those who are not familiar with it. Dictionary.com does a similar thing for all of its definitions, so there is a basis for this method, at the minimum.